# customize table view cell with own label

Tags: ios, uitableview

The nameLabel doesn't work. When I run the application, the following error occurs:
UITableViewCell nameLabel]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1fc4e090. But if i set the nameLabel as textLabel, it works.

Below is my code:

```
@interface ViewController ()
{
     NSMutableArray *books;
 }
@end

- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    Book *book1 = [Book new];
    book1.name = @"The adventures of tintin";
    book1.imageFile = @"tintin.jpg";


    Book *book2 = [Book new];
    book2.name = @"Avatar";
    book2.imageFile = @"avatar.jpg";
    books = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:book1, book2, nil];
}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{<br>
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"BookCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableV dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    //MyBookCell *cell = [tableV dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault  reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    }
    //if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[MyBookCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault  reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    }
    Book *bk = [books objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.nameLabel.text = bk.name; (customised label)

    return cell;
}
```

This is the header file for the custom table cell

```
@interface MyBookCell : UITableViewCell 
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *nameLabel;

@end
```

Comment: how did you customize the cell ?

Comment: Where is `nameLabel` added? `UITableViewCell` doesn't have any such properties.

Comment: thanks!! I shall add in the custom cell class code too.

Answer (score 2):

That is because UITableViewCell don't have a property named nameLabel.
Assigning textLabel.text is right
Or you can implement custom cell class, and there have fields with the proper names for you
Then instead of

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableV dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
```

you should call

```
MyCustomCell* cell = (MyCustomCell*)[tableV dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier];
if(cell == nil){
    NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyCustomCell"owner:self options:nil];
    cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
}
```

Comment: check if you load the correct .nib file, i will fix my post right now

Comment: Thanks!! I shall add in my custom cell code too to see if there is any error in that

Comment: yup i loaded the correct nib file . The name of the cell inside quotes (@"MyCustomCell) (in red) must be the same as the name of the table cell (MyCustomCell) in blue (with reference to ur code)?

Comment: nope. @"MyCustomCell" in red should be the name of your .xib file of your cell, in blue - that is the name of your class. They can be different

Comment: ok thanks a lot!! Then if I named my identifier: static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"MyCustomCell"; and then name the (@"MyCustomCell") in red, will both of these values clash?

Comment: You should read some tutorial on how to make custom tableViewCell, I think you won't have any problems after that

Answer (score 0):

Ther is no property like nameLabel for `UITableViewCell`.
If you subclassed the `UITableViewCell`, you need to type cast it to your own custom class like:

```
YourClass *cell = (YourClass *)[tableV dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
```

Also allocate it like:

```
cell = [[YourClass alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault  reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the following style to load custom UITableViewCell.

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CellCustom";
CellCustom *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:CellIdentifier owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
}
cell.nameLabel.text = @"Text";
```

Comment: Thanks!! The name of the identifier (in red) can be the same as the name of the cell (in blue)?

Comment: It should be same so that it will be a PERFECT REUSE of Cell.

Comment: Hmm ok thanks!! But when i named both as the same, the application crashed with an NSInvalidArgumentException

Comment: Make sure that CellIdentifier should be the name of the class.